# Does rebuild Index update the indexes of referenced table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

Suppose I have `Entity1(column1)` and `Entity2(column1, column2)`. `Entity1(column1)` references `Entity2(column2)`.

Both columns have indexes.

Does rebuild Index update the indexes of referenced table in SQL Server ?

Comment: No.  Rebuilding the indexes on one table only affects that table.

Comment: It will not update referenced table indexes